# Source code for chrome plugin "NaCl Development Environment"

Tags: google-chrome, google-nativeclient

I am looking for source code of Google chrome plugin "NaCl Development Environment". Not sure if source code for it is yet open. Can someone please help me with it.

Comment: I don't think this question belongs here at Stack Overflow. You should move this question to a different SE site.

Answer (score 1):

The source for the NaCl development environment can be found in the [naclports](https://code.google.com/p/naclports/) repository. You can browse it here https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/naclports.git/+/master/ports/devenv/